# SOSL No Result in Apex (Not Test Mode)

Tags: apex, sosl, dynamic-sosl

I want to query matching Accounts based NRIC Passport No AND Service Agent looking up to custom object Agent__c with a set of Ids (for bulkification) and i'm using:

- FIND '999999' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Service_Agent__c,
  NRICPassport_No__c, Last_Policy_Date__c, LifeAsia_Client_Number__c
  WHERE Service_Agent__c IN ('a0M5D000000o42nUAA'))

On Apex transaction (trigger specifically), just returns empty list:

- List item

'(())'

But when I run on Anonymous Window, results brings up the expected sample records already on the database:

- System.debug([FIND '999999' IN ALL FIELDS RETURNING Account(Name, Service_Agent__c, NRICPassport_No__c, Last_Policy_Date__c, LifeAsia_Client_Number__c WHERE Service_Agent__c IN ('a0M5D000000o42nUAA'))]);

Result:

- 15:11:46:127 USER_DEBUG [1]|DEBUG|((                              Account:{Name=Jeremy Lin, Service_Agent__c=a0M5D000000o42nUAA, 
  NRICPassport_No__c=999999,
  LifeAsia_Client_Number__c=LA666666, Id=0015D00000QF7d8QAD,
  RecordTypeId=0127F0000009gh7QAA},                                 Account:{Name=Kobe Bryant,
  Service_Agent__c=a0M5D000000o42nUAA, NRICPassport_No__c=999999,
  LifeAsia_Client_Number__c=LA111111, Id=0015D00000Tu4ufQAB,
  RecordTypeId=0127F0000009gh7QAA}))

My code is inside Without Sharing inner class method so sharing should not affect it.

On Test Class and I set "SeeAllData=true" to use the sample user i'm using on the UI as the System.runAs() user, the results shows up and test classes are passing as expected.

Really weird behaviour that when that same user is navigating on the UI, the results are empty on the apex debugs.

By the way, Account is on Private Settings. So I believe it shouldn't matter since we are running on System context. Unless I'm missing something that SOSL doesn't honor WITHOUT SHARING.

Comment: can you check that all the placeholder is correctly replaced in the trigger?

Comment: yeah, my test classes are passing. it is when i invoke it from UI (logging as a regular user/ non-system admin profile) that the values on SOSL doesn't show up. But SOQL with same conditions/filters shows the records up.

Comment: So, from test classes you are getting empty list. Is that correct assumption?

Comment: Test Class are showing values accurately through Test.setFixedSearchResults(), i mean there should be no problem with my code logic because I get my expected results. It is on the debug statements when I do the testing on the User Interfrace (creating a record using a regular user profile), etc

Comment: What is the total number of records in the database table?

Comment: 9 account records, i'm expecting 2 matches as shown on the debug statement above running the same SOSL query string

Comment: Have you checked record sharing settings for these non-admin users, if these records  are visible for these users?

Comment: I specifically used "WITHOUT SHARING" inner class to enclose my code logic to make sure everything in it runs in system context. As mentioned, it works fine on Test Classes even if that non-admin user is on System.runAs()

Comment: I found out that if I use System Admin on UI, the record shows up. So am I missing an info here that SOSL will ALWAYS honor private sharing settings even if inside WITHOUT SHARING ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that SOSL still honors the FLS. I thought Apex should be system context, but on the running user profile, i gave access to the fields being searched by the SOSL on apex, then the results appeared. No documentation indicating it on the SOSL/SOQL developer guide.